# Having problems with fitting content in div with css grid

Tags: html, css, overflow, css-grid

I'm playing around with Css Grid and having problems with fitting overlaying content.
There is a top level container defined as css grid (class="container"), then content grid (class="content") which splits into 3 rows (header, label, rows).
Header is just a header, label contains labels for rows and rows is a content of "table".

Here is what it looks like:
[image]

When I resize window I got scroll bar on the right but it's for the whole page. Instead I would like to scroll only rows not the whole page.
[image]

Here is the the StackBlitz working example:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ayujp5

I guess it's simple but having problems with understanding how height is calculated and where and how overflow properties should be defined.

```css
p {
  font-family: Lato;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 30px 1fr 30px;
  grid-template-rows: 30px 1fr 30px;
  grid-template-areas: '. . .' '. content .' '. . .';
}

.content {
  grid-area: content;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 50px 30px 1fr;
  grid-template-areas: 'header' 'label' 'rows';
}

.header {
  grid-area: header;
}

.label {
  grid-area: label;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 4fr);
  align-items: center;
}

.rows {
  grid-area: rows;
  height: 100%;
}

.row {
  background-color: pink;
  margin: 5px 0px;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 25px;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="header">Header</div>
    <div class="label">
      <div>Name</div>
      <div>From</div>
      <div>To</div>
    </div>
    <div class="rows">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="label">
          <div>1</div>
          <div>1999/01/01</div>
          <div>1999/12/01</div>
        </div>

      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="label">
          <div>2</div>
          <div>1999/01/01</div>
          <div>1999/12/01</div>
        </div>

      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="label">
          <div>2</div>
          <div>1999/01/01</div>
          <div>1999/12/01</div>
        </div>

      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="label">
          <div>3</div>
          <div>1999/01/01</div>
          <div>1999/12/01</div>
        </div>

      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="label">
          <div>4</div>
          <div>1999/01/01</div>
          <div>1999/12/01</div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Please post your [example] into a stack snippet `<>`.

Comment: You can give your content (the box you want to be scrollable a `max-height: 300px;
  overflow-y: auto;`. If you now exceed 300px in height on your content, a scrollbar will appear and the content is scrollable.

Comment: @Kameron there is a link to StackBlitz example https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ayujp5

Comment: @Laisender I would like this to be reactive - depends on the window size. If it's full screen I don't want t limit to anything.

Comment: @Paulie_D see your point. Added.

Comment: Well, your content is stacked vertically so the width of the window doesn't really matter right? If you would want to make it responsive you should take a look at css media queries to dynamically change the `max-height` property. //EDIT if you mean resizing the window vertically you can do the same thing and base the media query on your window height instead of window width.

Comment: @Laisender that would do the job. I know I can also calculate the height of a content box with something like that: .pin-table {
  height: calc(100vh - 125px);
  overflow: auto;
} But I thought that there is a smarter way without hardcoding values

Comment: If you use `calc` you have a dynamic value because `vh` is a dynamic unit of measure. I think this is fine

Answer (score 0):

I go with height calculation `.pin-table { height: calc(100vh - 125px); overflow: auto; }` but if anyone has better idea feel free to write.